# Erro em código por classes

Tags: java, javafx

Boas.Comecei agora a estudar a programação em java que inclui varias classes em que uma chama outra. Porem estou a depararme com um erro que nao consigo entender. Procurei codigos de efeito semelhante e nao consigo descobrir uma diferença nitida do erro.
O objetivo é criar uma classe que faz um desenho em forma de comprimido(Cumprido),e outra que desenha uma grelha desses comprimidos.

No codigo do desenho tenho isto:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Pill  {  
private Pane pane;
public void pill(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color leftColor, Color rightColor)
{       
    Rectangle leftRect= new Rectangle(x,y,width/4,height);
    leftRect.setStrokeWidth(0);
    leftRect.setFill(leftColor);
    pane.getChildren().add(leftRect);

    Rectangle rightRect = new Rectangle(x+width/4,y,width/4,height);
    rightRect.setStrokeWidth(0);
    rightRect.setFill(rightColor);
    pane.getChildren().add(rightRect);

    Ellipse leftEllipse = new Ellipse(x,y+height/2,width/4,height/2);
    leftEllipse.setStrokeWidth(0);
    leftEllipse.setFill(leftColor);
    pane.getChildren().add(leftEllipse);

    Ellipse rightEllipse = new Ellipse(x+width/2,y+height/2,width/4,height/2);
    rightEllipse.setStrokeWidth(0);
    rightEllipse.setFill(rightColor);
    pane.getChildren().add(rightEllipse);

}
} // END class Pill
```

Que compila e ja experimentei colocar numa classe á parte e executa sem problema.
Onde está o erro é neste:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Drawing  {  
private Pane pane;
private void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(
        e -> Platform.runLater( () -> {Platform.exit(); System.exit(0);} ));

    // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    // TODO    
        // 
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html
    this.pane = new Pane();
    this.pane.setPrefSize(900, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(this.pane, Color.WHITE));
    primaryStage.show();

    Pill pill = new Pill (150,100,300,200,Color.BLACK,Color.GRAY);   //Aqui dá um erro(Constructor Pill cannot be applied to class Pill cannot be applied to given types).
    this.pane.getChildren().add(pill);//Aqui da outro erro(No suitable method for add(pill).

    this.drawGrid();
} // END start

public void addShape(Shape shape)
{
    Platform.runLater(() -> this.pane.getChildren().add(shape));
}

/** execute this method to start the program
 * executing the code in method start(Stage primaryStage) 
 */
public static void start()
{
    Drawing drawingApp = new Drawing();
    drawingApp.launch();
}

public void launch()
{
    // Initialises JavaFX:
    new JFXPanel();
    // Makes sure JavaFX doesn't exit when first window is closed:
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
    // Runs initialisation on the JavaFX thread:
    Platform.runLater(() -> start(new Stage()));
}

public Drawing() 
{
    super();
}

public void drawGrid(int x, int y, int nLines, int nColumns, int width, int height, Color leftColor, Color rightColor)
{  
    nLines=3;
    nColumns = 4;
    for(int i = 300;i<=nLines*350;i+=350)
    {
        for(int j = 200; j <=nColumns*250;i+=250)
        {
            Pill p = new Pill (i,j,width,height,Color.BLACK,Color.GRAY);  // Dá um erro igual ao primeiro.
        }
    }
}

} // END class Drawing
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema do seu código está na chamada do construtor da classe `Pill`, uma vez que não existe um construtor que atenda ao que foi chamado na classe `Drawing`. Como não foi definido um construtor com os parâmetros da chamada que é feita nesta última, o código não consegue compilar

Uma possível solução seria renomear o método `public void pill(...)` para `public Pill(...)`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
public class Pill  {  
    private Pane pane;
    public Pill(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color leftColor, Color rightColor){
        ...
    }
}
```

Note que ainda existem dois problemas conceituais no seu código:

1 - Construtor não tem tipo de retorno;

2 - Construtor precisa ter o mesmo nome da classe (não esquecer que o Java é case sensitive!).